# How can I set up a single user that can edit multiple sites' files with correct default permissions?

Tags: nginx, permissions, user-management, groups

How can I achieve this setup:

There is a primary user that I use to ssh into the server and edit all files for multiple sites.

The various sites are stored in the `/srv/www` directory, so `/srv/www/site1`, `/srv/www/site2`.

There is a different user created for each site that Nginx will use to run the site (apparently this is good for security).

I want to be able to have all files in `/srv/www/site1` be owned by the `site1` user and belong to the `site1` group.  I want to be able to edit these files and create new ones with my primary user while still keeping the owner site1 and group site1.

I understand that I need to set the default `umask` somehow, and I may need to add my primary user to each site's group, but I can't seem to make this work.  Any help, or is this even a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set SUID and SETGID on the directory (chmod u+s directory and chmod g+s directory), in this way all files created under "directory" will belong to the user owning that folder no matter which user is creating them, also permissions will be kept.